# application migration from weblogic 10.2.0 to jboss 6.1.0

Tags: java, jboss6.x

I am new to Jboss server. I am migrating the J2ee application from  Weblogic 10.2 to JBoss EAP 6.1.0. While migrating I am getting the below error message. Kindly assist if anyone knows the solution.

The Application successfully gets deployed on the server but when i try to access the application through localhost, it throws a NullPointerException.

ERROR MESSAGE:

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) java.lang.NullPointerException

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at javax.naming.NameImpl.(NameImpl.java:264)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at javax.naming.CompositeName.(CompositeName.java:214)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.naming.util.NameParser.parse(NameParser.java:49)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.parseName(NamingContext.java:491)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:183)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:179)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at com.trifecta.pfizer.dao.UserProfileDAO.populate(UserProfileDAO.java:51)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at com.trifecta.pfizer.servlet.PfizerSiteController.doFilter(PfizerSiteController.java:394)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at com.trifecta.pfizer.servlet.PfizerSiteController.performTask(PfizerSiteController.java:163)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at com.trifecta.pfizer.servlet.PfizerSiteController.doPost(PfizerSiteController.java:546)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)

17:34:16,811 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

please help me in resolving the issue?

CODE:

```
try
        {

            if(sqlHome == null)
            {
            /*  Properties jndiProps = new Properties(); 
                jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory"); 
                jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"jnp://localhost:9990"); 
                jndiProps.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
        */      // create a context passing these properties 

                Context ctx = new InitialContext(); 
                System.out.println("check1...");
                //Object obj = ctx.lookup("SQLHelperSFOHome");

                //java:app/SQLHelperSFO             
                System.out.println("check2...");

                //sqlHome=(SQLHelperSFOHome)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(obj,SQLHelperSFOHome.class);

                //System.out.println(PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ctx.lookup("SQLHelperSFOHome"),SQLHelperSFOHome.class).toString()+"2");
                sqlHome = (SQLHelperSFOHome)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ctx.lookup("SQLHelperSFOHome"),SQLHelperSFOHome.class);
            }
            sqlsfo = sqlHome.create();
            sqlsfo.initialize(DATASOURCE_JNDINAME);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new DataAccessException("UserProfileDAO","populate",e.getMessage());
        }
```

I tried changing the initial context in the following manner:

```
Properties jndiProps = new Properties(); 
                    jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory"); 
                    jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"jnp://localhost:9990"); 
                    jndiProps.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");

Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
```

Also, The sysout statements used in this method are not displayed on the console.

Comment: Well, you haven't posted any code here. At a guess, you're still trying to use a `t3` initial context. JBoss doesn't use the WebLogic `t3` protocol, so you'll need to change how you do that.

Comment: I tried changing the initial context. Still the same error persist.

Comment: Since the error includes `javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)` I'm thinking you haven't changed it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
ctx.lookup("EJBclassName");
```

we used :

```
ctx.lookup("java:global/EARname/EJBprojectName/EJBclassName!AbsoluteNameOfEJBClass");
```

it worked.